# Is Chrome Frame really the only choice for improving Raphael performance in IE?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using Raphael 2.1 to draw 15 lines at the same time.  Each lines is made up of 50 2 pixel paths. Performance is best in Safari and Chrome, good in FF, weak in Opera, and chokes in IE9.  Microsoft says that SVG will run in IE9, but Raphael.svg returns false in IE9.

I've been reading posts related Raphael and IE all day, and the only solution that I've seen for improving Raphael's performance in IE9 is to install Chrome Frame.

Has anyone encountered any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael uses svg in IE9 and work with reasonable performance. You have to be careful that IE is not being forced into IE8 standards mode (which frequently happens). If IE9 falls back to IE8 standards then it will end up using VML, which is very slow, and there is no efficient alternative to SVG in general in IE8 or below.

When faced with this problem using IE8 I ended up using divs and css to achieve rendering of lines, rectangles and text. Since that's all I required it was very fast even in IE8, helped out by buffering the divs inside the container. If your problem is simple enough, you may wish to consider a pure DOM solution. See: https://github.com/Matt-Esch/simpleCanvas.js for inspiration.

Comment: You're right about IE9 being forced into IE8 standards mode.  It took me a long time to figure out why that was happening.  It turns out that I simply had a misplaced <title> tag and that error was blocking my DOCTYPE declaration.